# Filter Method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to create an array of names for a search results page

Here is the structure of the json:

```
 data = {
  "artists": [
    { "artistName": "a" },
    { "artistName": "b" },
    { "artistName": "c" },
    { "artistName": "d" },
    { "artistName": "e" }
  ]
}
```

So far this is my failed attempted:

```
data.artists.filter(artistName)
```

How would I correctly use the filter method here? Would using Reduce be better some how?

Comment: Do you want to collect all names in a list? `["a","b","c","d","e"]`?

Comment: You have to supply a predicate to the filter: `filter(obj => obj.artistName === someValue)`

Comment: Can there be duplicate values in your array?

Comment: how will the expected output look like

Comment: user7 has the desired outcome that I would like yes. and no duplicates

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @EddieTaliaferroII then update your question and don't answer in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to avoid possible duplicates, the solution would be more tricky than just using `map`:

```js
var data = {
 "artists": [
  {"artistName": "a"},
  {"artistName": "b"},
  {"artistName": "b"},
  {"artistName": "b"},
  {"artistName": "b"},
  {"artistName": "c"},
  {"artistName": "d"},
  {"artistName": "e"}
 ]
};

var list = Object.keys(data.artists.reduce((a, {artistName}) => (a[artistName] = 1) && a, {}));

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `map`

```js
let data = {
   "artists": [
  { "artistName": "a" },
  { "artistName": "b" },
  { "artistName": "c" },
  { "artistName": "d" },
  { "artistName": "e" }
   ]
 };

let result = data.artists.map(e => e.artistName);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: thats exactly the result I wanted. Thank you very much Ed! haha

Comment: Happy to help @EddieTaliaferroII